# Fixed background on <td> broken in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table, background-image

I discovered that if you have a background image with `background-attachment: fixed` on a table data (`<td>`) element or another element with `display: table-cell`, it's broken in Firefox (at least in version 26.0), but works correctly in Chrome and Safari, for example.

To see what I mean, take a look at this quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Stopa/sbcJL/2/

Scroll down so that the the table is out of viewport and then scroll back up and in Firefox you should see that the background is being repeated weirdly. Here's a screenshot for reference:

[image: http://imgur.com/fePFcI0]

Does anyone know of a way to fix it or why it behaves like this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Firefox 26 (OSX). No weird repetitions when I scroll down and up again.

Comment: i can only see a work around , using <table> as bg holder and any <td> but .bg with a background to hide table bg : http://jsfiddle.net/sbcJL/3/ , funny bug indeed